# Go Back to Start If no input is entered (Bat File) (#2)

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

This is a to follow-up question:
[Go Back to Start If no input is entered (Bat File)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770779/go-back-to-start-if-no-input-is-entered-bat-file)
Now for another final Touch and my file is perfect :)
Here's the relevant code part:

```
:: Delete variable %F%
SET "F="
set /p F=Folder or a File Trget:
attrib +s +h +r %F%
```

IF I Set Non Input, the file makes all the relevant files in the same folder and with the same extension (as in `attrib +s +h +r *.bat`) ,(in this case, bat) in to system files

I apologize for the bad wording

The complete procedure of this script (it's not the all script onlly on part of it)

```
:Hide
@echo off
cls
Color 0c

ECHO.
ECHO.
:: Delete variable %F%
SET "F="
set /p F=Folder or a File Trget:
attrib +s +h +r %F%


@echo off
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO   ######################################################
ECHO   #                                                    #
ECHO   # 1 - Set Other System Attribute To a Folder or file #
ECHO   # 2 - Remove System Attribute From a Folder or file  #
Echo   # 3 - Exit                                           #
ECHO   #                                                    #
ECHO   ######################################################
ECHO.
ECHO.

:: Delete variable %A%
SET "A="
SET /P A=Set Your Choice And Press Enter: 
ECHO Loading .........

IF "%A%"=="1" GOTO Hide
IF "%A%"=="2" GOTO Show
IF "%A%"=="3" GOTO Exit

GOTO Hide
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Always take filename it quotes becouse it can have spaces.
2. Delete quotes from filename. More: set /?

   ```
   set F=%F:"=%
   ```
3. 1. Make sure the input is not empty. Command 'if not "%F%"==""' - checks that input isn't empty. Command 'if EXIST "%F%"' checks that file exist.

      ```
      :: Delete variable %F%
      SET "F="
      set /p F=Folder or a File Target:
      set F=%F:"=%

      if not "%F%"=="" if EXIST "%F%" attrib +s +h +r "%F%"
      ```
   2. If you have too many commands that can't be runned without input you can add procedure in end of file and call it

      ```
      if not "%F%"=="" if EXIST "%F%" call :HideChecked

      :: There are your code. Remember, that call :Label always returns back & keeps batch execution. Read more: call /?
      :: So there your code ends. And new procedure starts.

      :: Prevent crazy parsing
      exit /b

      :HideChecked
          attrib +s +h +r %F%
      :: exit /b == return back
      exit /b
      ```
4. Always say to user, where is his error

   ```
   if not "%F%"=="" if EXIST "%F%" call :HideChecked

   if "%F%"=="" (
       echo You must choose something
       REM in 'IF ()' your can use only REM for comments.
       REM >nul - means command 'pause' will print nothing (except errors)
       pause>nul
       goto Hide
   )
   if NOT EXIST "%F%" (
       echo No such file. File list:
       REM dir /? for help
       dir /P/B
       pause>nul
       goto Hide
   )
   ```
5. In start of file add 'goto Input'. After each procedure (:Hide :Show :Exit) add 'goto Input' to prevent crazy parsing.

   ```
   :: At start of file
   goto Input

   :: There can be some code

   :Show
       :: And there
   goto Input

   :Hide
       @echo off
       cls
       Color 0c

       ECHO.
       ECHO.
       :: Delete variable %F%
       SET "F="
       set /p F=Folder or a File Target:
           set F=%F:"=%

       if not "%F%"=="" if EXIST "%F%" call :HideChecked
       if "%F%"=="" (
           echo You must choose something
           REM in 'IF ()' your can use only REM for comments.
           REM >nul - means command 'pause' will print nothing (except errors)
           pause>nul
           goto Hide
       )
       if NOT EXIST "%F%" (
           echo No such file. File list:
           REM dir /? for help
           dir /P/B
           pause>nul
           goto Hide
       )

   goto Input

   :Input
                       @echo off
       CLS
       ECHO.
       ECHO.
       ECHO   ######################################################
       ECHO   #                                                    #
       ECHO   # 1 - Set Other System Attribute To a Folder or file #
       ECHO   # 2 - Remove System Attribute From a Folder or file  #
       Echo   # 3 - Exit                                           #
       ECHO   #                                                    #
       ECHO   ######################################################
       ECHO.
       ECHO.

       :: Delete variable %A%
       SET "A="
       SET /P A=Set Your Choice And Press Enter: 

       IF "%A%"=="1" GOTO Hide
       IF "%A%"=="2" GOTO Show
       IF "%A%"=="3" GOTO Exit

       echo You must choose something
       pause>nul

       GOTO Input

   :: Prevent crazy parsing
   exit /b

   :HideChecked
       attrib +s +h +r "%F%"
   :: exit /b == return back
   exit /b
   ```

Comment: Wow you Re-write everything, Can you please simplify the explanation? and if there is any side note please Show it outside the script because it's pretty confusing

Comment: Ok after trying to contain your script in my file, I ran into another problem ..
Everything worked fine until i tried to perform the operation on a file that have a name in foreign language (Hebrew in this case, the Shell don't know how interpret that language)
the File send me a error and shuts itself down

Comment: About Hebrew - i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I sat on your code and figure it out, I must say it's very clever what you did there:)
Oh by the way I was wrong he has no problem with Hebrew files he has a problem with files whose names consist of two words I believe the problem is here:     ':: Delete variable %F%
    SET "F="
    set /p F=Folder or a File Target:
    
    if not "%F%"=="" if EXIST "%F%" call :HideChecked
    if "%F%"=="" (
    echo You must choose something
    REM in 'IF ()' your can use only REM for comments.
    REM >nul - means command 'pause' will print nothing (except errors)
    pause>nul
    goto Hide
    )'

Comment: Oh. You must take filename in quotes: attrib +s +h +r "%F%". I added that in answer

Comment: I'm pretty new here and I'm not accustomed to local habits

Comment: lol I found my problem I drag the folder into the window (and therefore automatically "" added to the file direction ) so adding a "" in the code itself creates an error (""%F%"")

Comment: well we can use command: set F=%F:"=% to delete quotes ("). Look more in aswer - i edited it again. P.S: can u mark my answer in another your question?

Comment: One Last question
exit \ b is written at the end of each procedure
Or only at the end of the file?

Comment: at the end of each procedure. This command must be writed to prevent executing code of other procedures

Comment: Ok Thank you very much for the help I really have no words to really thank you enough

Comment: I feel really bad but there is still the problem of the non input (probably as a result of the change that was implemented regarding "")
I get this error
 ="=="" if EXIST ""=" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Ok I'm Happy to say That I managed to solve whole of problems thanks to you. I solved one problem by using IF errorlevel 1 goto :label Thanks again I learned a lot from you and without you I could not Finish writing it. if you would like to see the file you can download it from here http://db.tt/1yq551r